# View a subfolder in the same window as its parent?

Tags: c#, windows, shellexecute

I have a parent folder and it contains subfolders and other files ( text files, images, executables .. ) all laying together in the same path (actually, it's the path to their parent folder).

```
SendKeys.SendWait("sub");
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

The two lines above perform the action I need; which is opening the folder called 'sub' in the same window of its parent folder view without opening a new one.(The picture shows the situation I would like to avoid, let's say I would like to find the best way to perform an equivalent action of "selecting" a sub folder and then pressing ENTER to open it in the same window without launching a separate and a new one)

[image]

Aany suggestions ? I read about default verbs in ShellExecuteA() but that doesn't seem to work for me;my code was

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace testFaza
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        static extern int ShellExecuteA(int hwnd, string lpOperation, string lpFile, string lpParameters, string lpDirectory, int nShowCmd);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = @"sub\";
            ShellExecuteA(0, null, path, null, null, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I released, then when it executes, the output result is something like the first picture :

[image]

EDIT :

```
string path = @"sub\";
dynamic ws = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");       
ws.Run("explorer.exe /select, " + (char)34 + path + (char)34);
```

then a SendKey to hit {ENTER}, this is the best solution I came through till now.

Comment: I think you have the Windows Explorer setting "Open folders in new window" set. When I run the SendKeys it doesn't create a 2nd explorer window

Comment: Same for me. The option you mentionned is actually disabled, and the SendKeys commands work fine. I'm looking for a more advanced way to perform the same thing, WinAPI functions like ShellExecute() family, maybe ?

Comment: Why not roll your own with a TreeView. No SendKey just your own application completely under your control.

Comment: Further explanation please ? I would like to know more about the TreeView solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explorer.exe supports a command line argument of **/SELECT** which will select files/folders, eg the sub folder:

```
string sPath = "c:\bin\release\sub";

//Start a Window and reliably select a subfolder
Process.Start("explorer.exe", " /select," & sPath);

//Open the folder
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: The idea of passing arguments to **explorer.exe** was of help. Thank you